# Powershell pop message with visible timer in it

Tags: powershell

I trying to show a powershell pop message with a timer in it. For now I am able to show the popup with a custom message. I am trying to include a visible timer in the popup message for 10mins. After timer ends (10mins) pop should automatically close.

```
$org="Company."
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null
$Form = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
            $Form.TopMost = $true

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("IMPORTANT !!`n
Please the application upgrade will start in 2mins`n

Click on OK to Start the installation",$org, "OK", "Warning", "Button1", "DefaultDesktopOnly")
```

Comment: I believe you would have to write your own WinForms code for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` for that, but  if you just want to close it automatically after some time then `Wscript.Shell` can help..

```
$org="Company."
$timeout = 5 # in seconds
$ws = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
$intButton = $ws.Popup("IMPORTANT !!`n
Please the application upgrade will start in 2mins`n
Click on OK to Start the installation",$timeout,$org, 0)
```

If you however want to show a live timer, message boxes are not the tools for that but you can create a form and use a timer with event handler... see an example in this answer: [Powershell - Handle Windows Forms Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467209/powershell-handle-windows-forms-events)